# IPv6 Link-Local Multicast on Twisted

Tags: sockets, twisted, ipv6, multicast

I am trying to write the same Ping-Pong Multicast-Example on [Twisted-Example-Page](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html#multicast-udp). Though the Example works on IPv4 addresses for multicast-group, I replaced the line

```
self.transport.joinGroup("228.0.0.5")
```

with

```
 self.transport.joinGroup("ff02::1")
```

which is the **link-local IPv6 address** so the clients with addresses `fe80::` can receive the multicast message.

This does not work though the error received is such:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: 
address 'ff02::1' not found: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported.
```

I have been looking around the API Reference but don't seem to get a proper way to execute this.

This is what I get for `cat /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   testbed

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Any help would be great thanks.

#### Update

I was using the debian package which was version **13.2** and now have updated to **16.0** but this problem still exists.

Comment: Apparently, IPv6 literals in `joinGroup` are [not yet supported in Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6597).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dubu so it makes sense to use basic Python for IPv6 since it works for me. I thought it would make things easier if I used Twisted. Thanks a lot. Also can you write it an answer here for future reference. Will make it an official answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay so apparently there is still work in progress for assigning **IPv6 addresses** when using the `self.transport.joinGroup()`.

Hence this will not work

```
self.transport.joinGroup('ff02::1')
```

nor will this

```
self.transport.joinGroup('ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001')
```

One could always go back to basic socket programming in Python where the works get done with IPv6 multicast on both real networks and also on the computer. For the code please check [this Link](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/sockets/mcast.py)